# Populate DataSet into a ComboBox and fill a TextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, dataset

I'm trying to fill a ComboBox from a DataSet while a column of the DataSet should fill a TextBox, too.

Example table:

```
sid |  sname | surl
---------------------------
  1 | Google | www.google.com
  2 | Bing   | www.bing.com
  3 | Yahoo  | www.yahoo.com
```

Now I want `Google`, `Bing`, etc. as the `SelectedText` in the ComboBox, while the `SelectedValue` is `1`, `2`, etc.
When I select `Google`, I want `www.google.com` filled into the TextBox.

The code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim tb As DataTable = Dataset1.Table1

        ComboBox1.DataSource = tb
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "sname"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "sid"

        TextBox1.Text = DataSet1.Table1.FindBysid(ComboBox1.SelectedValue).surl
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        TextBox1.Text = DataSet1.Table1.FindBysid(ComboBox1.SelectedValue).surl
    End Sub
End Class
```

Afaik, the initial selection works as it should.
The ComboBox selects `Google` and setss `TextBox1.Text` to `www.google.com`.
But then it rans on the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: "Invalid Conversion of Type DataRowView
>   to Type Integer.

This happens on the `SelectedIndexChanged` Event.
I really don't know why the first TextBox assignment works pretty well while the second one in the event runs on a convertion error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code to test the functionality of the [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource) and [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding) classes.

Build a DataTable with some fields (as provided in the question); use the DataTable as the DataSource of a `BindingSource` object.

The BindingSource is then set as the DataSource of a ComboBox (here, `ComboBox1`).
The `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are also set to the desired Columns (set these properties possibly before assigning the control's DataSource).
Then add a Binding to a TextBox `Text` property using the same DataSource (the BindingSource object previously defined).

When the ComboBox `SelectedItem` changes (in code or because of a user selection), the `TextBox.Text` property will be updated accordingly:

```
Friend dtSource As BindingSource = Nothing

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim dt As New DataTable("TestTable")
    dt.Columns.AddRange({
        New DataColumn("sid", GetType(Integer)) With {
          .AutoIncrement = True, .AutoIncrementStep = 1, .AutoIncrementSeed = 1
        },
        New DataColumn("sname", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("surl", GetType(String))
    })

    dt.Rows.Add({Nothing, "Google", "www.google.com"})
    dt.Rows.Add({Nothing, "Bing", "www.bing.com"})
    dt.Rows.Add({Nothing, "Yahoo", "www.yahoo.com"})

    dtSource = New BindingSource(dt, "")

    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "sid"
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "sname"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dtSource

    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(
        New Binding("Text", dtSource, "surl", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!