# Display a value in a TextBox that is linked to a string in my ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am making a Windows Form App to manage a simple Invoice.
I created a ComboBox, then I added 3 strings using the Items collection property settings:

```
PRODU
EVNT
DISC
```

When I select, for example, `PRODU` in my ComboBox I want it to show a fixed price that is linked to `PRODU` in a TextBox on the same page.
I am completely new to coding and I see a lot of answers but I cannot seem to fix it.
Can anyone help me?

I have some understanding of SQL so it can be linked to a Database or just front end only. 
The code I have gives me syntax errors.

```
Public selected As String

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Case "PRODU"
           (selected Case = 45)
        Case "EVENT"
           (selected case = 50)
            TextBox1.Text = selected.ToString()
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim selValue As Integer
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Case "PRODU"
            selValue = 45
            TextBox1.Text = selValue.ToString()
        Case "EVENT"
            selValue = 50
            TextBox1.Text = selValue.ToString()
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You have to learn about DataBindings. This is similar example: [Populate DataSet into a ComboBox and fill a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950476/7444103). Of course you don't need a DataSet, you can use your own object, a class with a couple of properties that hold your values, create a list of these objects and set the `List(Of Class)` as the `ComboBox.DataSource`, specifying what properties are used as DisplayMember and ValueMember (as shown in the example). Add a binding to other controls that use the same datasource.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jimi ! Worked perfectly fine ! and thanks for ure patience!! i really really apreciate it ! next time i have a question i will be more specific with more code etc..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Populate DataSet into a ComboBox and fill a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949953/populate-dataset-into-a-combobox-and-fill-a-textbox)