# ItemName to Listbox from SQLTable and its value to textboxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to load the **ItemName** from sql table to **Listbox**
and get **ItemId**, **ItemName** and **Details** values to textboxes.

[image]

so far I have this code everytime I open or load the window its shows the itemName in the listbox. which is good.

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * FROM Items")
cmd.Connection = connection
Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable()
adp.Fill(dt)
ListBox1.DataSource = dt
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "ItemName"
```

but the problems is:
what do I have to do, if I click one of the items in the listbox and it will automatically show the itemId, ItemName and Details in the textboxes from sql table. I need some help. thank you!

[image]

Comment: Use a BindingSource to handle the DataTable and add DataBindings to your Controls. Simple example here: [Populate DataSet into a ComboBox and fill a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950476/7444103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sync the selection of a `ListBox` item with `TextBox`es use a `BindingSource`. When you add `DataBindings` to the `TextBox` you pass the name of property you wish to bind to, the `BindingSource` variable and the `DataMember` (the column name) you wish to bind.

Most database objects need to be disposed. `Connection` and `Command` have `Dispose` methods that need to be called. Luckily vb.net provides `Using...End Using` blocks to handle this for us. This will also closed the connection. Connections should be declared with the `Using` block in the method where they are used so they can be disposed.

You don't need a `DataAdapter`. Just use a `DataReader` and load the `DataTable`.

You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. You can also pass the `CommandText` and the `Connection` to the constructor of the `Command`.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt = GetDataFromSql()
    Dim BndSrc As New BindingSource()
    BndSrc.DataSource = dt
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "ItemName"
    ListBox1.DataSource = BndSrc
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSrc, "ItemID")
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSrc, "ItemName")
    TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSrc, "Details")
End Sub

Private Function GetDataFromSql() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using connection As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("select * FROM Items", connection)
        connection.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: this is great. thanks! what about if its an Image?  should it be something like PictureBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSrc, Image) to get the image fromsql binary data?

Comment: You would need to bind to Image property of the PictureBox. Assuming the data is stored as VarBinary you would need to convert to a Byte() and then a MemoryStream. For more detail ask a new question.

Comment: hey Mary, I got the new question, I've been asking. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69490007/14629356

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    con = New SqlConnection("ConnectionString")

    con.Open()

    cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[Item_Details]", con)

    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While rdr.Read

        ListBox1.Items.Add(rdr(1))

    End While
    con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseClick

    Try
       
        con = New SqlConnection("ConnectionString")
        con.Open()
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select *  from Item_Details where itemname='" & ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() & "'", con)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            TextBox1.Text = row(0).ToString()
            TextBox2.Text = row(1).ToString()
            TextBox3.Text = row(2).ToString()
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```