# Get Image from SQL using Listbox to picturebox VB

Tags: vb.net

i'm trying to get the image from SQL to picturebox using Listbox in in VB.

here is my sql sample table.

[image]

and here is my VB Design form, so what I'm trying to do is when I load the form, if an item in the listbox is selected, i want it to get the image(Binary Data) from sql to picturebox in vb net.

[image]

and the code I'm working with it give me this error:
[image]

VB full code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    connect()
    Dim co As New SqlConnection("Data Source=WXCQSDQSD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=food;Integrated Security = True")
    co.Open()
    Dim com As New SqlCommand("SELECT Image from Items where ItemName = '" & ListBox1.SelectedIndex & "'", co)
    Dim img As Byte() = DirectCast(com.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(img)

    Dim dt = GetDataFromSql()
    Dim BndSrc As New BindingSource()
    BndSrc.DataSource = dt
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "ItemName"
    ListBox1.DataSource = BndSrc
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSrc, "ItemID")
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSrc, "ItemName")
    TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSrc, "Details")
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

End Sub
Private Function GetDataFromSql() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=WXCQSDQSD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=food;Integrated Security = True"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("select * FROM Items", connection)
        connection.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Your `Form1_Load` method is not correctly disposing of your DB connection resources.

Comment: Use a `SqlDataReader` and its `GetSqlBinary()` method to read `binary`/`varbinary` columns. You should not be using the obsolete `image` column data-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the picture retrieval from the `Form.Load`. We have selected all the data in the `GetDataFromSql` function. The magic happens in the `ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged` method.

The `SelectedIndexChanged` will occur as a result of the code in the `Form.Load` and every time the selection changes. When we bind the the list box to to binding source the entire row is added as a `DataRowView`. We can use this to get the data in the Image column. First check if the field is null. Next cast to a byte array. Take the byte array and pass it to the constructor of a `MemoryStream`. Streams need to be disposed so it is in a `Using` block. Finally the stream can be assigned to the `Image` property of the `PictureBox`.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt = GetDataFromSql()
    Dim BndSrc As New BindingSource()
    BndSrc.DataSource = dt
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "ItemName"
    ListBox1.DataSource = BndSrc
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSrc, "ItemID")
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSrc, "ItemName")
    TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSrc, "Details")
End Sub

Private Function GetDataFromSql() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=WXCQSDQSD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=food;Integrated Security = True"),
        cmd As New SqlCommand("select * FROM Items", connection)
        connection.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim row = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
    If row("Image") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim b() As Byte = DirectCast(row("Image"), Byte()) '< ------ Cast the field to a Byte array.
        Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(b)
            PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
        End Using
    Else
        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

I switched the code over to a database I have available for testing. Even though it is not your database, I am sure you will be able to follow the code.

Here is the schema of my database.

[image]

The main difference is I moved the `DataTable` to a class level variable so it can be seen from all methods. I changed the `GetDataFromSql` to a `Sub`. It adds the data to the class level `DataTable` (`Bounddt`). The `AddItem` method first gets the `Byte()` from a file. The row is added to the `DataTable` with an `Object` array with elements that match the DataTable.

```
Private Bounddt As New DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GetDataFromSql()
    Dim BndSrc As New BindingSource()
    BndSrc.DataSource = Bounddt
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "CustomerID"
    ListBox1.DataSource = BndSrc
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSrc, "CustomerID")
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSrc, "CustomerName")
End Sub

Private Sub GetDataFromSql() 
    Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=****;Initial Catalog='Small Database';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"),
    cmd As New SqlCommand("select * FROM Sales.Customer", connection)
        connection.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Bounddt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    'Return dt
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim row = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
    If row("Picture") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim b() As Byte = DirectCast(row("Picture"), Byte()) '< ------ Cast the field to a Byte array.
        Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(b)
            PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
        End Using
    Else
        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub AddItem()
    Dim picture = GetByteArr("C:\Users\maryo\OneDrive\Documents\Graphics\Animals\squirrel.png")
    Bounddt.Rows.Add({5, "George", 74, 62, "George", picture})
End Sub

Private Function GetByteArr(path As String) As Byte()
    Dim img = Image.FromFile(path)
    Dim arr As Byte()
    Dim imgFor As Imaging.ImageFormat
    Dim extension = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)
    'There is a longer list of formats available in ImageFormat
    Select Case extension
        Case "png"
            imgFor = Imaging.ImageFormat.Png
        Case "jpg", "jpeg"
            imgFor = Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg
        Case "bmp"
            imgFor = Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid image format")
            Return Nothing
    End Select
    Using ms As New MemoryStream
        img.Save(ms, imgFor)
        arr = ms.ToArray
    End Using
    Return arr
End Function
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AddItem()
End Sub
```

Comment: there is a slight problem I am having, whenever I execute or add another item in the listbox, the listbox doesnt update the items unless I restart the form again. I tried duplicating the form_load and the selectedindex event in a button, so whenever I click the button it runs the code again but it doesn't seems so work.

Comment: @PotatoPythonLearner I should have asked you to provide a new question but I just added an answer as an edit.

Comment: this is great! thank you soo much!

Answer (score 0):

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim rdr As SqlDataReader
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Private Const cs As String = "ConnectionString"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con = New SqlConnection(cs)
    con.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[Item_Details]", con)
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While rdr.Read
        ListBox1.Items.Add(rdr(1))
    End While
    con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseClick
    Try

        con = New SqlConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select *  from Item_Details where itemname='" & ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() & "'", con)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            TextBox1.Text = row(0).ToString()
            TextBox2.Text = row(1).ToString()
            TextBox3.Text = row(2).ToString()
            Dim data As Byte() = row(3)
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream(data)
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: @potato python Learner This code will be useful to you

Comment: i don't know. it doesn't seem to show the picture from the sql to picturebox of the selecteditem in the listbox

Comment: Hi @potato python Learner Did you tried with this code? It's working like what you are expecting.